# How I can retrieve Latest NAV for Mutual Fund from Amfi RSS site

Tags: .net, rss

favorite  Hello Everyone,

I want retrieve daily latest NAV based on AMFI RSS Feeds tell me how I can retrieve it.

Thanks..

Comment: In what programming language? There's surely an RSS parsing library available, whatever it is.

Comment: see I using WPF C# so this is stadalon app.

Comment: if u have any good odea for this plz tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use .NET as a development platform, you can use the Rss20FeedFormatter class ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.rss20feedformatter.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know basic excel. Here is how you can get the AMFI Mutual Fund data using an excel connection. To get the current date data in a excel sheet create a connection to AMFI (current working URL is   https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt ) Once you have raw data in excel, use TextToColumn function to split the data across columns, then use formula to pick column that you need.

You can use this samlle formula to extract data you want from the downloaded data (13Feb is worksheet name)
=IFERROR(INDEX('13Feb'!$E$1:'13Feb'!$E$119999,MATCH(B2,'13Feb'!$B$1:'13Feb'!$B$119999,0)), "***")

The image below is self explanatory. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have created an API for my personal use.

It's at [https://yash.info/mfnav/get_mf_nav.php?c={SchemeCode}](https://yash.info/mfnav/get_mf_nav.php?c=%7BSchemeCode%7D)

The list of scheme codes can be seen at https://yash.info/mfnav/list.php

AMFI publishes a daily list of latest NAVs in a text file at https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt

I have written a script to download this file and parse and enter data into a table. A cron job runs it at 5 AM every day. Then I have built an API to fetch the latest NAV for a single scheme which I use in an Excel Macro to update the latest value of my various MF investments.